# How to recursively read a folder and its sub-folders and search for a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new to shell scripting, so I'll do my best to summarize everything.

I am writing a script with the goal of going into a directory, searching for a file (readme.txt) within each subfolder and follow instructions specified in file (readme.txt).

Code I have written so far:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Creating directory that the files are going to be moved into

if ! (mkdir /dir1/dir2/backupdir> /dev/null); then
    echo "Directory already exists. "

else
    echo "Directory successfully created. "

fi

# Moving old files to backup directory

cd /dir1/dir2/maindir-*
find /dir1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name "readme.txt" | while read z

do
    if grep -i move "$z" > /dev/null; then

        mv /xdir0/$z /dir1/dir2/backupdir
        # /xdir0/ is the parent directory of /xdir1/
        # readme.txt file does not include /xdir0/ so I added it when moving the files
        
    fi
               
done
```

**Current Output**: /dir1/dir2/maindir/subfolder1/readme.txt

Within 'maindir' there are several sub-folders.

maindir/subfolder1
maindir/subfolder2
maindir/subfolder3

Each subfolder has a readme.txt file. The contents of readme.txt would look something like this:

```
Date: 2021-08-12
Applicable Version: xx.x
Description: Quick summary of files

Steps to apply:
 1. move the following files into a backup location
    * xdir1/xdir2/xdir3/xdir4/filename-*.jar
    * xdir1/xdir2/xdir3/xdir4/filename1-*.jar
 2. done. work completed.
```

The script would parse through each line after "move" is recognized and stop at the "Done. Work completed" line as all files have been moved to the backup directory I created.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I that the exact contents of `readme.txt`? If not, edit your question and include the exact contents.

Comment: Hi David, "Date", "Applicable Version" and "Description" have been added from readme.txt file. These are the exact contents. FYI - There is no spaces between "Date" "Applicable Version" and "Description" in readme.txt file. It would not let remove the spaces in between them as I edited the post.

Comment: I formatted the text file for you. Double check that it now reflects the correct `readme.txt` contents. (including the spacing and whether the lines that have the files to move really begin with a `*`, and that the `1. move` and `2. Done ...` lines really begin with `1.`and `2.` and whether than can be more than one set of 1. move` and `2. Done ...` lines.)

Comment: Thank you, David. I removed the spaces and changed from "Done. Work completed." to "done. work completed". Yes, lines that have files to move start with a * and 1. move and 2. done begin with 1. and 2.  I suppose there could be more lines added, but for now I wanted to keep it as is and add to it later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mkdir -p newfolder` which will create it or silently continue if the folder already exists. This way you would not have to check if the folder exists.

You do not need the `sleep 1`

You can actually first use `find -mindepth 1 -type f -name "readme.txt"` to find the folders where you have the readme:

```
find /dir1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name "readme.txt"|while read z
do
  if grep -i move "$z" > /dev/null;then
    ... do your mv magic
  fi
done
```

Comment: I updated my source code to reflect the changes made. However, when I run the script I get the following error -  line 77: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: do we need to guess what your whole script looks like? :) This error suggest some of the `if`'s are not properly closed or the loops are not closed.. Share your whole script, or try to debug locally where your issue is

Comment: That is the whole script I am running. Fixed the "unexpected end of file" error and the code is running fine now (removed for loop). However, it is not reading the file path of the .jar files specified inside the readme.txt file and moving them into the backup directory I created. It is instead moving the readme.txt file itself into the /dir1/dir2/maindir location.

Comment: It looks like the $z variable is the pwd or the directory path of the readme.txt file. How can I make it to where it is the directory path for the .jar file instead?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a pipe, you start calling `find`:

```
# find all 'readme.txt' files from "$DIR" and subdirectories and make a loop
# for each one.
your_backup_location=/home/user/blah/blah/foo/bar

find "$DIR" -name 'readme.txt' -print | while read file
do
    # Assuming this is executed in subdirectory
    # xdir1/xdir2/xdir3/xdir4, where readme.txt was found...
    # $file contains the readme.txt full path from starting dir.
    echo "executing commands from $file" >&2 # print it on stderr
    ( # this will start a subshell, so we can work in the directory where readme.txt is.
        cd "$(dirname "$file")"  # move to dir where readme.txt is located.
        . readme.txt # read commands from readme.txt file.  Protect comment lines with # char.
        # as commands are read into the shell, no need to export the 
        # shell variable ${your_backup_location} (see below)
    ) # exit subshell, so we are back in start directory.
done
```

and the `readme.txt` format should be a shell commented text file (explaining in comments what needs to be done) interspersed with shell commands to execute:

```
# Date: 2021-08-12
# Applicable Version: xx.x
# Description: Quick summary of files

# Steps to apply:
#  1. move the following files into a backup location
#     * xdir1/xdir2/xdir3/xdir4/filename-*.jar
        mv filename-*.jar ${your_backup_location}
#     * xdir1/xdir2/xdir3/xdir4/filename1-*.jar
        mv filename-*.jar ${your_backup_location}
#  2. done. work completed.
```

This way you will start a subshell on every directory in which you have a `readme.txt` file.  You can specify many filters on `find` command, so try to output only what is needed to do some actual work, and don't try to spawn a subshell for each subdirectory just to do nothing.  And don't use `find` to just descend one level each time, as you will have a lot of `find` processes running to do almost nothing.

The idea is not to do unnecessary processing if you have no strict formatting rules to describe the actions to be done.  In this case, shell comments allow you to fully describe the operations, while you can better describe the operations with valid shell commands.  This saves a lot of `grep` and `sed` employed in other answers.